# How to fill UITableView with a data from Dictionary. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Please help me with filling table view cells with data from a dictionary. For instance, I have cell like so:

[image]

and for filling it with data I've started with overriding `cellForRowAt` method:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CurrencyCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrencyCell

    for (key, value) in currencies! {
        print("key is - \(key) and value is - \(value)")
    }

    // ?

    // cell.currencyLabel.text =
    // cell.askLabel.text =
    // cell.bidLabel.text =

    return cell
}
```

Printout of Dictionary here:

```
key is - EUR and value is - Rate(ask: Optional("30.8500"), bid: Optional("30.1000"))
key is - USD and value is - Rate(ask: Optional("26.3000"), bid: Optional("26.0500"))
key is - RUB and value is - Rate(ask: Optional("0.4150"), bid: Optional("0.3750"))
```

How to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put your data into an array ordered how you want it to appear in the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used a struct Rate to Reproduce your current Output

```
struct Rate {
    var ask : Float?
    var bid : Float?

    static var shared = Rate()

    mutating func initWithDictValues(_ currentRate : Rate) {
        self.ask = currentRate.ask
        self.bid = currentRate.bid
    }
}
```

**Currencies Array**

```
/// Array Declaration
var currencies = [String:Any]()

/// Add Values
currencies = ["EUR":Rate(ask: 30.8500, bid: 30.8500),"USD":Rate(ask: 26.3000, bid: 26.3000),"RUB":Rate(ask: 0.4150, bid: 0.4150)]
```

**Get All Keys in Separate Array so we can Dequeue cell Easily**

```
var keysArray = Array(currencies.keys)
```

**TableView Function**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CurrencyCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrencyCell

    /// Get CurrentKey
    let currentKey = keysArray[indexPath.row]
    let currentIndexKey : Rate = currencies[currentKey] as! Rate

    /// Assign Values
    cell.currencyLabel.text = currentKey
    cell.askLabel.text = currentIndexKey.ask ?? 0
    cell.bidLabel.text = currentIndexKey.bid ?? 0

    return cell
}
```

**Playground Output**

[image]

**Hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

By using this:

```
var valueArray: [Int] = []
var currencyArray: [String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for (key, value) in currencies! {
        print("key is - \(key) and value is - \(value)")
        currencyArray.append(key)
        valueArray.append(value)            
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CurrencyCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrencyCell

    //retrieve the key and value
    let value = valueArray[indexPath.row]
    let key = currencyArray[indexPath.row]

    //next use the value and key for what you need them

    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting your answer. I've already done this using: `let keys = Array(currencies!.keys); let values = Array(currencies!.values)`. But anyway I'll upvote your answer cuz u put your time and efforts :)

Comment: Having two separate arrays is the wrong approach. You want one array. Multiple arrays makes sorting and filtering much more difficult.

Comment: @rmaddy, can you give an example of this here, please?

Comment: @HarryMcGovern Look at any of the other answers that use a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

Using only one array is better for tableView data instead of using dictionary or more arrays.
To do this, you can create a struct to wrap all data a cell needs.

```
struct Currency { 
    let currency: String
    let rate: Rate
}
```

You can turn dictionary to Currency array or assign your data to Currency at first.

```
var currencies = [Currency]()
for (key, value) in currencies! {
    let currency = Currency(currency: key, rate: value)
    currencies.append(currency)          
}
```

Then use this array to cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CurrencyCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrencyCell
    let currency = currencies[indexPath.row]

    //assign data to cell

    return cell
}
```