# Dictionary data into custom table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have the Dictionay data as key value pairs. Here key is image and value is description of image. How do I insert that data into custom table view cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // **How do I insert image and description data here*****
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please show Data sample, So we can see how to Dequeue cell on basis of Data

Comment: Mean time you can also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130421/6080920

Comment: What are the properties of your `CustomTableViewCell`?